# Selenium: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally. DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

All of a sudden I am getting this error whenever `webdriver.Chrome()` is called. I have tried to use Options as other answers suggest but that doesn't seem to work either, as well as specifying the Chrome and chromedriver executable path. I have updated Chrome (85.0.4183.121) and chromedriver (85.0.4183.87) to the latest versions and tried other versions as well. I am on Ubuntu 20.04.
Any help is much appreciated.

```
  File "/home/fulco/projects/selenium/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "/home/fulco/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 76, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/home/fulco/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/fulco/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/fulco/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/fulco/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason it just stopped working in the vscode terminal. Otherwise it works just fine.